# Can anyone help me to find the file from where i rename product QTY

Tags: product, qty

How to find the file name and location in Magento 2?
I want to rename the Quantity to Qty as you can see in the picture

[image]

Comment: Did you try templete hints it will show the file location

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling magento template hints, by enabling this feature you will be able to see the bloks and templates used in each page.

[image]

To enable this feature go to:

[image]

```
Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes
```

For more details go [here](https://magecomp.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2/)